# Efficient serialisation of large list into a database?

Tags: python, mongodb, serialization, sqlite, memcached

I have about 29 million individual unicode elements I want to serialise into a database. My current solution uses SQLite, and incrementally sends a list of length 100,000 at a time:

```
cursor.executemany("insert into array values (?)", [list of length 100,000])
```

I thought this would be efficient enough, but after going to sleep and waking up (say 6 hours), and seeing it still hadn't finished, I thought otherwise.

**Would a MongoDB or memcached solution be more efficient?**

(feel free to suggest any more efficient method)

Comment: Please describe your problem.

Comment: Why do you want to store it to a DB in the first place?

Comment: To have an efficient, persistent array

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to choose memcached, please take case of the below mentioned note.

```
Memcached has a default setting of maximum data size that can be set as 1Mb. 
Any data size greater then that would require you to start the memcached explicitly stating the maximum size.
```

I really like using redis for storing data structures. As your requirement is not so very clear. I would be suggesting you to use redis, as you can store it in multiple fashion and use it interestingly.

Please read the documentation of the different data structures that can be stored on the redis.

http://redis.io/documentation

Comment: Thanks, I've been using Redis in the C# world (ServiceStack), so realised it was a choice. However getting Redis to work in Python on Windows seems NP complete >.< [bad joke, I know! :P]

Comment: Then you must close the question it seems.

Comment: So there is no non-Redis solution you could recommend?

Comment: The problem is the data is too large in number. Its a list and you will always be needing it fast and later you will feel a need to  implement some logic. The lua scripting branch is new but once it is stable, you can do amazing things on the server itself and save data transfer too and fro.Its my love for redis, that makes me say yes.

Comment: Mmm, looking forward to that branch being implemented. Is that integration comparable to the PLSQL (stored procedures) approach? - Also, I don't need the list to be a list database side, I just need to be able to insert it as a list, i.e.: in batch

Comment: Please refer to this link about the lua scripting branch in redis. http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/19321054250/redis-lua-scripting-is-badass

Answer (score -1):

Try spawning `gevent` threads e.g 10 and monitor how many records are processed in a given time, and try increasing the number. You should also look into `multiprocessing`